# Get notified when Objective-C dom updates are ready initiated from webview

Tags: javascript, objective-c, dom, webkit, jquery-events

I am programmatically updating the DOM on a WebKit webview via `DOMElement` objects - for complex UI, there is usually a Javascript component to any element that I add. This begs the need to be notified when the updates complete -- is there any such event? I know regular divs don't fire an `onload` or `onready` event, correct? The other assumption I had, which may be totally wrong, is that `DOMElement` updates aren't synchronous, so I can't do something like this and be confident it will meet with the label actually in the DOM:

```
DOMElement *displayNameLabel = [document createElement:@"div"];
[displayNameLabel setAttribute:@"class" value:@"user-display-name"];
[displayNameLabel setTextContent:currentAvatar.avatarData.displayName];
[[document getElementById:@"user-card-content"] appendChild:displayNameLabel];
id win = [webView windowScriptObject];
[win evaluateWebScript:@"javascriptInstantiateLabel()"];
```

Is this true?

I am using jQuery within the body of the html already, so I don't mind subscribing to a particular classes set of events via "live." I thought I might be able to do something like:

```
$(".some-class-to-be-added-later").live( "ready", function(){
    // Instantiate some fantastic Javascript here for .some-class
});
```

but have experienced no joy so far. Is there any way on either side (objective-c since I don't programmatically firing Javascript post load, or Javascript) to be notified when the element is in the DOM?

Edit: Based on **Anurag**'s answer, here's the code I came up with (works):

```
    function onButtonPanelChange() {
        console.log( "Button panel subtree modified", 7 );
        $(".panel-button").each( function(){
            console.log( "Button found " + $(this).attr( "class" ), 7 );
            if( !$(this).hasClass( "processed" ) ){ 
                $("#bottom-button-panel").unbind( "DOMSubtreeModified" );
                if( $(this).hasClass( "chat" ) ){
                    console.log( "Found chat button, instantiating", 7);
                    var chat_button = new Button( $(this), chat_button_def );
                    $(this).addClass( "processed" );
                }
                else if( $(this).hasClass( "get" ) ){
                    var chat_button = new Button( $(this), get_button_def );
                    $(this).addClass( "processed" );
                }
                $("#bottom-button-panel").bind( "DOMSubtreeModified", onButtonPanelChange );
                console.log( "Done with button change, rebinding", 7 );
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $("#bottom-button-panel").bind( "DOMSubtreeModified", onButtonPanelChange);
    });
```

Note that you hella need to unbind the event, since each subsequent change fires another event, and another, and another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a similar question that was asked an hour ago - [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)

To listen to changes on an element, use something like:

```
$("#someDiv").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("tree changed");
});
```

I haven't scripted the DOM through Objective-C, so don't know if there's a way to subscribe to DOM events with the Objective-C wrappers.

The `DOMSubtreeModified` modified event works on the iPhone. Just tested with [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/eQErD/1/).

Comment: well indeed. this is fantastic -- I'll try it out.